# Module not found while trying to test java module dependencies

Tags: java, java-module

I'm currently reading [Boyarksy & Selikoff's OCP Study Guide for Java SE 17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119864585) and have finally reached the **Modules** chapter. I've been trying, based on their written examples, to create two "test" modules, in order to see how this actually works. Of course, I know there are rare cases (if any) where we need to create modules by hand, because build tools already do this for us, but still just wanted to check how it works, to also have some bit of "low-level" knowledge about modularity in Java.

I plan to create two modules, one called `park` and the other one called `services`. `park` module should contain two packages, `props` and `employees`, while `service` module should only have one package called `parkcleaning`.
Both modules should have the following structure:

```
module_test [FOLDER]:

  > park [MODULE]
     > park.props [PACKAGE]
        > park.props.Bench [CLASS]
        > park.props.Bin [CLASS]
     > park.employees [PACKAGE]
        > park.employees.Cleaner [CLASS]

  > services [MODULE]
     > services.parkcleaning [PACKAGE]
        > services.parkcleaning.CleaningService [CLASS]
```

I've stored both my modules in a folder called `module_test`, which looks like this:
[image]

... with the `park` folder looking like this:
[image]

and its `module-info.java`:

```
module park {
    exports park.employees;
}
```

... and the `services` folder looking like this:
[image]

and its `module-info.java`:

```
module services {
    requires park;
}
```

Now, each folder contains files with the classes specified in the above hierarchy, so there's no need to display them. As you can see, `services` module has a dependency on the `park` module because my `CleaningService` class requires a `park.employees.Cleaner` field. Again, I think I don't need to display the class because that's all what it does.

I've been trying the following steps:

1. Compile the `.java` files from the `park` module (classes + the `module-info.java`) with the following command:

```
javac -p module_test park/employees/Cleaner.java park/props/Bench.java park/props/Bin.java park/module-info.java
```

which makes my `park` folder look like this:
[image]

(also, there are `.class` files both inside `employees` and `props` folders now)

2. Compile the `.java` files from the `services` module using:

```
javac -p module_test services/parkcleaning/CleaningService.java services/module-info.java
```

which gives me the following error:

```
services\module-info.java:2: error: module not found: park
        requires park;
                 ^
1 error
```

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the hierarchy of my folders, although I don't know what. I've also properly defined the package names inside the `.java` class files, but I still don't know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each module directory, your package hierarchy should be complete, starting at the root, with the `module-info` at the root.

So it should look like:

```plaintext
module_test [FOLDER]:

  > park [MODULE]
    > module-info [MODULE DESCRIPTOR]
    > park [PACKAGE]
      > props [PACKAGE]
        > park.props.Bench [CLASS]
        > park.props.Bin [CLASS]
      > employees [PACKAGE]
        > park.employees.Cleaner [CLASS]

  > services [MODULE]
    > module-info [PACKAGE DESCRIPTOR]
    > services [PACKAGE]
      > parkcleaning [PACKAGE]
        > services.parkcleaning.CleaningService [CLASS]
```

Then, in the directory of module `park`:

```bash
javac park/employees/Cleaner.java park/props/Bench.java park/props/Bin.java module-info.java
```

and in the directory of module `services`:

```bash
javac -p .. services/parkcleaning/CleaningService.java module-info.java
```

or:

```bash
javac -p ../park services/parkcleaning/CleaningService.java module-info.java
```